# How to add a background image to Windows Phone Panorama App

Tags: c#, xaml, background, windows-phone-8.1, panorama-control

I'm trying to add a background image to my Windows phone panorama application. When I add the image with XAML code, image can be seen in the preview. But when I run the app, I can't see the image. Size of the image I used 1536x1280

here is the XAML code I used;

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/back.png"/>
</phone:Panorama.Background>
```

Also I tried the following C# code;

```
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
        this.Background = imageBrush;
```

how I see in the visual studio preview
[image: how I see in the visual studio preview]

how I see in the emulator and the device
[image: how I see in the emulator and the device]

Comment: what is the build action of your image file?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. What is build action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the 'Build Action' of your Image file. (In your solution, right click on your image file, and look at it's properties).

If the 'Build Action' is `'Content'`, your code is right.

But if the 'Build Action' is `'Resources'`, you should modify the image path to:
***'ms-appx:///Assets/back.png'***

Answer (score -1):

I solved this same problem by doing these things:

- First in "Project" part of Visual Studio select "Add Exiting item"
- Select your image.

Remember to address your image correctly.